# Cannot store objects in my Google Cloud Storage from my Google App Engine Servlet (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using my App Engine to allow an app to upload a file.
The file is received in HTTP POST, and I'm trying to store it in Google Storage.

My Server code;

```
GcsFileOptions instance = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename("my-bucket", "file.dat");
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;

log.info("Saving " + fileName + " to " + instance);

outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
copy(req.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
```

The Log entry in the middle yields;

```
com.my.app.Servlet: Saving GcsFilename(my-bucket, file.dat) to GcsFileOptions [userMetadata={}]
```

This results in exception;

```
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetriesExhaustedException: RetryHelper(5.644 s, 10 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1@1af95fcc): Too many failures, giving up
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
    at com.my.app.Servlet.saveFile(Servlet.java:128)
    at com.my.app.Servlet.doPost(Servlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
... <Cut by submitter>
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.getInstance(LocalRawGcsService.java:186)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.access$000(LocalRawGcsService.java:109)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.ensureInitialized(LocalRawGcsService.java:194)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.beginObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.beginObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:92)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.call(GcsServiceImpl.java:74)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl$1.call(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:108)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.<init>(LocalRawGcsService.java:123)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.getInstance(LocalRawGcsService.java:184) 
    ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. This question (in a similar situation) was already answered here: [How to fetch the file list from gcs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32613909/how-to-fetch-the-file-list-from-gcs)